# Trouble downloadig an thumbnail image in O365 Video using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dotnet-httpclient

I am running into an odd issue with trying to access a thumbnail image stored on O365 video via C#.  I can access the REST API with no issue at all, I just add the `Authentication: Bearer <token>` to the header and I am off an running.  The trouble is with a basic image URL that I get back from a specific video.

```
https://<mytenant>.sharepoint.com/portals/Channel1/pVid/myvideo.mp4.PNG?VideoPreview=1
```

When I access that URL from a browser it works 100% of the time.  When I try to access it via the `httpclient` object, I am getting a `401 Unauthorized` error.

The best I can figure is that the authorization header token is not being honored when accessing a basic URL.  Which makes me thing that I need something else like a cookie?  However I cannot seem to figure out which one.  Looking for any advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Pass credentials instead and yes you need an authentication cookie. Here is a sample:

```
private static async Task<string>getWebTitle(string webUrl) 
{ 
//Creating Password 
const string PWD = "softjam.1"; 
const string USER = "bubu@zsis376.onmicrosoft.com"; 
const string RESTURL = "{0}/_api/web?$select=Title"; 

//Creating Credentials 
var passWord = new SecureString(); 
foreach (var c in PWD) passWord.AppendChar(c); 
var credential = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(USER, passWord); 

//Creating Handler to allows the client to use credentials and cookie 
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credential }) 
{ 
    //Getting authentication cookies 
    Uri uri = new Uri(webUrl); 
    handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies(uri, credential.GetAuthenticationCookie(uri)); 

    //Invoking REST API 
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler)) 
    { 
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear(); 
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format(RESTURL, webUrl)).ConfigureAwait(false); 
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 

        string jsonData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 

        return jsonData; 
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks! However I don't have the credentials as I am using the O365 oAuth and Federation model (using the O365 login page).  What I think I need is a way to take an OAuth token and "convert" it to a FedAuth cookie.